# Resuming of activity if alive

Tags: android

I have 2 activities
       1. **activity1**
       2.  **activity2**

**activity1** is running. On an event from **activity1**, I wanted to switch to **activtiy2**

The conditions are

1.create new activity and run if **activity2** is not alive.
 2.Resume **activity2** if it is alive

In both cases it should not  close **activity1**

How to achieve this requirement.

Comment: call startActivity for activity2, activity1 will not close and will resume when activity2 finishes ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write in Activity2 onCreate as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
                //If activity is not loaded first time
              }
    else
     {
        //activity is loaded first time
     }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the perfect answer I'm looking for.

Comment: `savedInstanceState` will be non-null if the screen gets turned. But when the Activity gets started the second time - it will be a separate object, `savedInstanceState` will be null but there will be two instances of the activity

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
         | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control whether activity1  gets killed or not in that scenario unless you explicitly call `.finish()` on it. If you don't - it will not be destroyed untill you press Back button, call `.finish()` or memory manager decides it needs the mem occupied by the background activity.

To avoid re-creating activity2, you should use [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in manifest, read up on it – you're probably looking for `singleInstance`, `singleTask` or `singleTop`, see the link for the differences.